# function to generate the following signal

Tags: wave-equation

I don't know If this is the right place to ask but if not just tell me and I'll ask on another StackExchange forum!

I'm currently working on a tiny game project and I'm trying to generate a basic day/night cycle. To do so, I would like to create the following periodic function

[image: The wanted signal]

- Where **T1** is day
- **T2** is transition duration
- And **T3** his night

The value of the function fluctuate between 0 and 1 and is used with a color gradient to change the map texture and illumination.

For me, this looks like a mix between a triangle and a cyclic square wave. But to be honest, due to my lack of Mathematics skills I don't know how to process to put this wawe into a formula.

Thank in advance

Comment: I think you need piecewise-defined function